# Removing spacing between TD elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

There are annoying gap between my td elements. I want it to be joined together.

http://jsfiddle.net/zj6mk/4/

I have tried different elements, but none have worked:

```
 border-collapse:collapse;
 cellspacing:0;
 border-spacing:0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` to table

```
<table style="height: 400px; width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zj6mk/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
<table style="height: 400px; width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <div style="height: 200px;">aa</div>
        <div style="height: 200px;">aa</div>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;cellspacing:0;">
        <div style="height: 350px">aa</div>
        <div style="height: 50px">aa</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see I added cellpadding="0" & cellspacing="0" and the gap disappears.

Here the JsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/zj6mk/7/

Or simpler and more "attractive" - use `width:100%;` in your css for your `div`.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
html,body{

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

so outer white spaces will be removed
and

```
<table style="height: 400px; width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

so inner white spaces will be removed
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Aa8c/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<table style="height: 400px; width: 100%;">
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;padding:0px">
        <div style="height: 200px;">aa</div>
        <div style="height: 200px;">aa</div>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;padding:0px">
        <div style="height: 350px;">aa</div>
        <div style="height: 50px;">aa</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> try adding `padding:0px` to td